# cocoa: detect inactive states of all the running application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Greetings!
I am very new to this cocoa and I am trying to achieve something like activity monitor. i have list of all the running applications and I would like to observe these app and get notified when any app goes to [Not Responding] state like in activity monitor. Checked NSWorkSpace and NSRunningApplication but didnt got much help.

Please enlighten me on this.

Thanks in advance
Ankit

Comment: Try using AppleScript's System Events to see if a given application is currently running.

Answer (score 0):

See the Accessibility framework. This lets you [access application instances and their properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXAccessEnabling/cocoaAXAccessEnabling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001059-BAJJIBFA) such as "active" state. Try [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXNotifications/cocoaAXnotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001061-CJBBDEAD) and see if that gets you around having to poll app state.